# unable to run allure on codeceptjs

Tags: plugins, codeceptjs

I am trying to run

> codeceptjs run --plugins allure

but getting an error

> error: unknown option `--plugins'

I added the plugins to codecept.json with enable true, did all what written on 
https://codecept.io/plugins/#allure

but still getting this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check your packages to make sure you're using the latest version of codeceptjs. Cause allure plugins is introduced since 1.4.1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/codeceptjs

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have installed Java 8 or a later version.
2. Make sure you have successfully installed allure-commandline by running:

`npm install -g allure-commandline --save-dev`

3. Allure plugin must be added to codecept.conf's plugins section as documentation states